# Converting javascript objects to xml with array emelents as <item><item>

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to serialize arrays embedded in javascript object to get XML structure in which elements of array are present *item* tags.

I need to keep my current API structure that uses *item* tags for each array element. I tried numerous node packages: xml2js, xml-js, js2xmlparser, jsontoxml but they aren't able to produce xml I need.

My json object looks like this:

```
{ 
  response: { 
    status: 200,
    message: "OK",
    books: [
      {title: "A Game of Thrones", release: "August 1996"},
      {title: "A Clash of Kings", release: "February 1999"},
      {title: "A Storm of Swords", release: "November 2000"}
    ]
  }     
}
```

I would like to see each element of result array in  tags:

```
<response>
  <status>200</status>
  <message>OK</message>
  <books>
    <item>
      <title>A Game of Thrones</title>
      <release>August 1996</release>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>A Clash of Kings</title>
      <release>February 1999</release>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>A Storm of Swords</title>
      <release>November 2000</release>
    </item>
  </books>
</response>
```

most of libraries produce array in XML in this form:

```
<response>
  <status>...</status>
  <message>...</message>
  <books>...</books>
  <books>...</books>
  <books>...</books>
</response>
```

Comment: Is it feasible to just map the original object? Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rmf4nbc6/ Do you happen to need this format for every array or just for this one?

Comment: I need to do that for every array that can be in response object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function from [this article](http://raathigesh.com/Converting-Json-Object-To-XML-String-In-JavaScript/) loops each property of a JS object and adds encloses the value in a tag depending on the property name.

```
function objectToXml(obj) {
        var xml = '';

        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (obj[prop] == undefined)
                continue;

            xml += "<" + prop + ">";
            if (typeof obj[prop] == "object")
                xml += objectToXml(new Object(obj[prop]));
            else
                xml += obj[prop];

            xml += "<!--" + prop + "-->";
        }

        return xml;
    }
```

With some tweaks, here's what I have come up to achieve your requirement:

```js
function objectToXml(obj) {
  var xml = '';

  for (var prop in obj) {
    debugger;
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      continue;
    }

    if (obj[prop] == undefined)
      continue;

    xml += "<" + prop + ">";
    if (typeof obj[prop] == "object") {
      if (obj[prop].constructor === Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj[prop].length; i++) {
          xml += '<item>';
          xml += objectToXml(new Object(obj[prop][i]));
          xml += "</item>";
        }
      } else {
        xml += objectToXml(new Object(obj[prop]));
      }
    } else {
      xml += obj[prop];
    }
    xml += "</" + prop + ">";
  }

  return xml;
}

console.log(objectToXml({
  response: {
    status: 200,
    message: "OK",
    books: [{
        title: "A Game of Thrones",
        release: "August 1996"
      },
      {
        title: "A Clash of Kings",
        release: "February 1999"
      },
      {
        title: "A Storm of Swords",
        release: "November 2000"
      }
    ]
  }
}));
```

Of course this function returns a string without any formatting whatsoever but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, not the best solution but it works. You need to watch out for other pitfalls lie escaping special characters since this XML is created 'lets say' manually.

Comment: Of course. But that's for you to improve. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Using **xml2js**,

I think you need to have this structure :

```
var obj = { 
  response: {
    status: 200,
    message: "OK",
    books: {
      item: [
        {title: "A Game of Thrones", release: "August 1996"},
        {title: "A Clash of Kings", release: "February 1999"},
        {title: "A Storm of Swords", release: "November 2000"}
      ]
    }     
  }
};
```

What you could do to rebuild the expected structure is :

```
var resp = obj.response;

// Option 1
for (var key in resp) {
    if (resp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        resp[key] = Array.isArray(resp[key]) ? resp[key] = { item: resp[key] } : resp[key] = resp[key];
    }
}

// OR

// Option 2
var keys = Object.keys(resp);
keys.forEach((key) => Array.isArray(resp[key]) ? resp[key] = { item: resp[key] } : resp[key] = resp[key] );
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that I need to rebuild the structure of my javascript object.
Tried to do that with [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/traverse) by traversing the object, but with no luck, falls int infinite loop when I modify current array element by adding nested array

Comment: `var xmlReady = traverse(data).map(function(curObj){
if(Array.isArray(curObj)){
this.update({item: currObj});
}
})`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this using xml2js lib:

```
    var xml2js = require('xml2js');

    var response = {
      response: {
        status: 200,
        message: "OK",
        books: {
          item: [
            {title: "A Game of Thrones", release: "August 1996"},
            {title: "A Clash of Kings", release: "February 1999"},
            {title: "A Storm of Swords", release: "November 2000"}
          ]
        }     
      }
    }

    var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
    builder.buildObject(response);
```